# Cannot find generated compatible screen manifests, file a bug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling, runtime-error

I fetch a error on my old android studio project.

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find generated compatible screen manifests, file a bug`

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NznoU.png)

Comment: The old project was built on Android studio?
It was not built in Eclipse?

Comment: no. It build in android studio. Now I try to update my app it is not working